# Unable to get environment variables from proc filesystem

Tags: linux, process, process-management

I have following script.

```
$ cat foo.sh
NAME=bar
while true
do
  echo "My name is $NAME"
done
```

As per my understanding, /proc/pid/environ contains environment variables used by the process.
But when I examine, I don't find `NAME` variable defined in /proc//environ.

```
$ sh foo.sh &
$ strings /proc/$(pidof sh)/environ |grep NAME
HOSTNAME=localhost
LOGNAME=root
```

I suspect my understanding about /proc/pid/environ is wrong, can you confirm if the file contains only system variables, and not the variables used inside the process?

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't unsetenv() modify /proc/pid/environ?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/302970)

Comment: Also: [Why can't I print a variable I can see in the output of env?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/389555)

Comment: In any case, you're just showing shell variable assignments, not environment variables (and there's no such thing as *system variables*). environment variables are lists of `name=value` strings passed upon *executing* commands. Shells *can* mark some of their variables so they're passed in the list of env strings of future commands they execute.

Comment: I tried exposing it as system variable as well, it doesn't seems to work.
```
$ cat foo.sh
export NAME=bar
while true
do
  echo "My name is $NAME"
done
```

Comment: Try `NAME=value grep -w NAME /proc/self/environ`, `/proc/<pid>/environ` contains the env strings in the `envp[]` parameter passed to the last `execve()` system call the process performed.

Comment: Perhaps more explicitly, `/proc/.../environ` contains the *initial* environment given to the process, it doesn’t reflect subsequent changes. So you’ll see it in Stéphane’s `grep` example, because `NAME` was set in the environment passed to `grep`.

Comment: @StephenKitt, not of a process. The `/proc/<pid>/environ` will initially be the same as the process' parent, and will be updated every time that process executes a command.

Comment: @Stéphane oops, yes, whenever `execve` is called.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas using `NAME=value grep -w NAME /proc/self/environ` will work, as we're defining the variable there itself (the NAME=value).

Comment: Yes, it works because the child process forked by the shell is *passing* `NAME=value` in the envp[] list passed in `execve("/usr/bin/grep", argv, envp)`. It would also work in a sh shell with `export NAME=value; grep -w NAME /proc/self/environ` because sh passes the list of its variables that have their *export* attribute set in the `envp` of all commands it executes. It would also work in `perl` in `$ENV{NAME} = "value"; system "grep", "-w", "NAME", "/proc/self/environ"` because `perl` passes the members of its `%ENV` hash as `key=value` strings in `envp` to the commands it executes, etc.